# Чтение и разбор pdf-файла

Tags: pdf, php

Подскажите библиотеку или технологию чтения и разбора `pdf` файла из php на составные части.

Мне необходимо выдернуть фоновую картинку, и текст. Для текста определить шрифт, положение, цвет. Если возможно, то еще и выдернуть с сохранением шрифт текста в файлик `ttf`, например.

`Fpdf` вроде только для создания годится. Поправьте меня, если я не прав, ссылкой на хороший пример.

Вопрос в стиле погуглите за меня, но я не смог найти - не знаю нужных слов для поисковика!

Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Comment: Наткнулся на тему на вашу, видимо 1й ответ поудачнее, спасибо.
сам тоже сейчас озадачен таким вопросом, вот что получит на ВиО гугла:
http://otvety.google.ru/otvety/thread?tid=28ee6a8d4490ab51&table=%2Fotvety%2Fuser%3Fuserid%3D03479807938430032613

Вам удалось найти решение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[parse pdf with php](http://www.conradish.net/pdfhi.php.txt)

Не все можно найти на русских сайтах.

Comment: Чет похоже на правду. Буду копать внутри, пока плюсую и огромное спасибо.

Comment: Удачи в раскопках)

Comment: Класс то, что нужно, но похоже немного устарел или его подпортили специально. Валится на read_ref методе. Без доки на формат по структуре пдфа даже не знаю как поправить. Может еще ссылоку кинете?)

Comment: https://github.com/adeel/php-pdf-parser

Comment: Спасибо, только что нашел его и хотел отписать: https://github.com/adeel/php-pdf-parser
Не хвататет пары классов разбора для других объектов но зато работает на ура! Пока только инфо вытаскивает и массив всякой непонятной шляпы)

Answer (score 1):

А если у гугла запросить просто php pdf?
Может тут есть то, что ты ищешь?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php
П.С. Сам лично не пользовался, никогда не стояло подобных задач.

Comment: Тут я уже был.) Еще раз пробежался по функциям - похоже все заточено на запись, а не на чтение. Не могу дельной ссылки найти с примерчиком. Но спасибо.