# Есть ли возможность средсвами PHP прочитать файл PDF?

Tags: pdf, php

Есть ли возможность средствами PHP прочитать файл PDF? 
Если есть, то как это осуществить? 
Где (на русском языке) можно подробнее прочитать про PDF формат?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[Вам сюда](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php)

Answer (score 0):

[тут обсуждалось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/52341/php-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pdf) что косательно чтения PDF средствами php

P.S. Нужно уметь понимать php код а не мануалы русским написаны!